# Chart.JS bar graph combined with line does not render correctly

Tags: javascript, c#, chart.js

I have a Chart that renders correctly as 2 scatter charts, I'd like to change the first dataset to a bar, but once I do it no renders correctly, but as a flat line.

My chart creation code is as follows:

```
    const chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'scatter',
        data: chartData,
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            onClick: onClickChart,

            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        min: -4,
                        max: 4
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    id: 'A',
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'right',
                    display: false,
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 0.4
                    }
                },
                {
                    id: 'B',
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'left',
                }]
            }
        }
        });
}
```

And then to fill the datasets:

```
    chart.datasets.push({
        type: "scatter",
        label: "Frequency",
        data: new Array<XYPair>(),
        borderColor: config.lineColors.red,
        borderWidth: 1,
        fill: false,
        yAxisID: "B",
    });

    chart.datasets.push({
        type: "scatter",
        label: "Ideal",
        data: new Array<XYPair>(),
        borderColor: config.lineColors.blue,
        borderWidth: 1,
        fill: false,
        yAxisID: "A",
    });

    // gauss segments
    for (let val in data.segments) {
        let x: XYPair = {
            x: data.segments[val].label, y: data.segments[val].count
        };

        chart.datasets[0].data.push(x);
    }

    // ideal line
    for (let val in data.gaussCurve) {
        let x: XYPair = {
            x: data.gaussCurve[val].x, y: data.gaussCurve[val].y
        };

        chart.datasets[1].data.push(x);
    }
```

My data is in X,Y pairs, which according to the documentation should work. I'm using X/Y data to match up the X-Axis between the line and area. It seems my xAxis gets messed up because the change. Could it because I did not load any labels?
If so how do you match up labels from different sets as one dataset has more poisst than the other.